# How to tell whether to add magnetic field lines or subtract?

Tags: electromagnetism

[image]

Hi there,

When you draw the magnetic field lines around these two current-carrying wires, after solving the magnetic field strength around each one (X and Y), how do you know whether to add them or subtract them? So in between the two wires, would you add or subtract, and at point P, would you add or subtract?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you mind rotating the image?

Comment: apply right hand thumb rule...for each wire

Answer (score 0):

You need to check their direction respectively and use vector addition to find the net magnetic field. For example, $$\vec{B}_{\text{net}}=\frac{\mu_0\:I}{2\pi r}(-\hat{z})+\cdots$$
In your case, you can just use Ampere right-hand rule to determine their direction and add them vectorially.